# Subfigures side by side with captions using minipage instead of subfigures

Tags: vertical-alignment, subfloats, minipage

I tried to insert side by side figures making a minipage instead of subfigures. The captions of the two figures are not aligned and are numbered ina wrong way.

I'd like to align captions and number the figures (a), (b) and the total figure fig. n with n the correct number (1 if the fig is the first in the document ecc).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{fig2a}
        \caption{Modello compartimentale mammellare (o mammillare).}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{fig2b}
        \caption{Modello compartimentale catenario.}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Principali topologie dei modelli compartimentali.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: If the `subcaption` package is loaded, a `subfigure` environment is nothing but a `minipage` environment with some minimal functionality to "number" the caption as a, b, c, etc instead of 1, 2, 3, etc. The `subfigure` environments take the same positioning specifiers as ` minipage` environments do. So, why is it that you don't what to use `subfigure` environments?

Comment: Hello @Mico, my goal is to learn to do the same thing in different ways.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to use `subfigure` environments but still generate captions that are numbered a, b, c, etc (or whatever else you do), you basically have to "reinvent the wheel" and come up with caption-related macros -- a problem that's been solved by the writer(s) of the `subcaption` package...

Comment: Thanks for your precious explanation @Mico, now it is clear!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To repeat what was already stated in the comments: A `subfigure` environment *is* already a `minipage` environment -- just one with some added capabilities related to creating captions.

Here's how I'd rewrite your code, mainly loading the `subcaption` package and using two `subfigure` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.475\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig2a}
    \caption{Modello compartimentale mammellare (o mammillare).}
    \label{fig-a}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.475\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig2b}
    \caption{Modello compartimentale catenario.}
    \label{fig-b}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Principali topologie dei modelli compartimentali.} 
  \label{fig:main}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: your answer is impeccable! Thank you for your efforts!

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi - You're most welcome!